# Betweenness Cetrality Brande's Algorithm

Tags: graph

I am trying to design Brande's algorithm for betweeness centrality in java, as shown here: http://www.inf.uni-konstanz.de/algo/publications/b-fabc-01.pdf on page 10. However, I do not understand what the sigma, d, or delta (at the bottom) are. Can someone explain them?